# If $f$ is absolutely continuous and monotonic on a compact interval, then the flat part of $f$ consists of at most a countable number of segments.

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions, absolute-continuity

I have a question that is seemingly somewhat similar to Froda's theorem.

Suppose $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ is absolutely continuous and monotonic with $f(0)=0$ & $f(1)=1$, and let $\Omega$ be the union of maximal segments (i.e. open intervals) on which $f$ is constant (if there are any). Is it true that the number of such (disjoint) segments is at most countable? I must know the answer to this question in order to resolve some measurability issue. Thanks a lot!

(add : my understanding from the first answer) : Now, let $\Sigma$ be the union of the maximal half-closed intervals (i.e. intervals of the form $(a_i, b_i]$, instead of segments of the form $(a_i,b_i)$) on which $f$ is constant. Then, the restriction $g$ of $f$ to $[0,1]/\Sigma$ is bijective so that the inverse $g^{-1} : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]/\Sigma$  is well-defined and bijective as well. (Note that I used the half-closed intervals instead of the segments in order to make the restriction g be injective.)  Now, since $g^{-1}$ is monotonic on the compact interval $[0,1],$ we obtain from Froda's theorem that the discontinuities of $g^{-1}$ are at most countable, implying that $\Sigma $ is a countable union of half-closed intervals, which in turn yields the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer speaks of a "basis" for a topology. But we don't need to know about that here.

A set of pairwise disjoint open intervals in $\mathbb R$ must be at most countably infinite because every open interval contains rational numbers (the proof of that can be an interesting exercise: between any two reals there is a rational). And there are only countably many rationals.

Comment: You are right. My question needed just a one line proof which is yours. Thanks.

Comment: OK, copycat. :P

Comment: @RiversMcForge : Your way of saying this requires familiarity with concepts that are not needed in order to understand this argument.

Comment: OP clearly understands basic topology. The concept of a "basis" a) isn't some incredibly deep, arcane idea and b) is literally the exact same as the idea posted here, which was just marginally reworded.

Comment: @Rivers McForge : I just now happened to find out that your answer can be directly used to deal with my next step of research. Many thanks.

Comment: @RiversMcForge : I believe in making things as simple as they actually are. And my answer is in no sense copied from yours nor a rephrasing of yours.

Comment: @Michael But insofar as your answer differs from mine, it’s less correct. Your argument hinges on $[0, 1]$ being *separable* (countable dense subspace), but not every open $\Omega$ in a separable space is a countable union of open sets. For that, you really do need *second-countability*. It’s true that the two are equivalent in metrizable spaces, but you have to actually incorporate that into your argument, not just gloss it over.

Comment: @RiversMcForge : You wrote: "not every open $\Omega$ in a separable space is a countable union of open sets". I wonder what that means. Every open set is a union of just one open set, so that's countable. Did you intend "open $\Omega$" to mean something other than an open set?

Comment: @RiversMcForge : Now it occurs to me that maybe what you meant was that not every open set in a separable space is a countable union of BASIC open sets. But that is not a deficiency in my answer. My answer applies only when the space is the real line. Every open set of the real line is a union of pairwise disjoint open intervals, and the fact that every open interval contains rational numbers is then used to show that there can be only countably many such intervals. Do you really think the use of some theorem that holds in all separable spaces is needed to show that?

Comment: @michael Yes, thanks for catching that. I meant not every open $\Omega$ in a separable space is a union of countably many “intervals” (ie basis sets for the topology). You need second-countable, not just separable, to guarantee this.

Comment: @michael My point is you have to do a *little* more legwork to go from “every open subinterval of $\Omega$ contains a rational point” to “$\Omega$ is a countable union of open intervals”. It’s not automatic, and there are indeed spaces where that would be false (like $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$ in the box topology).

Comment: @RiversMcForge : If a space has a countable subset that intersects every open set, then every set of disjoint open sets in that space has just countably many members.

Comment: @Michael That’s still kind of circular because you’re assuming every open set $\Omega$ in $\Bbb{R}$ is a disjoint union of open intervals.

Comment: @RiversMcForge : Every open set in the real line is indeed a disjoint union of open intervals. Why would that make anything circular? Moreover disjointness of the intervals of constancy of a monotone function is clear even if that didn't hold for _every_ open set.

Comment: @Michael Every open set in $\Bbb{R}$ is a union of open intervals, but not necessarily a disjoint one. Also, the intervals of constancy are *closed*, not open, which complicates the analysis slightly

Comment: @RiversMcForge : Every open set in $\mathbb R$ is a union of pairwise disjoint open intervals. But even if that were not so, the interiors of the intervals of constancy are seen to be pairwise disjoint because of the definition of monotoncity of functions.

Comment: +1 to compensate the undeserved downvote. Simplicity should be preferred anytime over complexity.

Answer (score 3):

If $\Omega \subset [0, 1]$ is *any* union of open intervals, then $\Omega$ can **always** be written as a countable union of open intervals. This is because $[0, 1]$ is [second-countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space): the open intervals with rational endpoints form a basis for the topology on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: I studied these materials a long time ago but almost forgot for now. Thanks a lot for reminding me of these. I feel that these will definitely be needed in the future to resolve other issues such as measurability of functions. I accepted the first answer because it can be more conveniently used to resolve my issue, not because it is more correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, could you please let me know whether my addition is justifiable? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need all of the concepts used in this answer. See my posted answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. And as you pointed out, it is very similar to Froda's Theorem. Actually, you can use the theorem to prove your statement.

Using Froda, you know that the number of discontinuities is countable. Now, if the number of constant intervals were uncountable, you would need to have an uncountable number os discontinuities, since every constant interval would have a different value (due to monotonicity), which is a contradiction. Hence, you have countable constant intervals.

Comment: Would it not just follow from the fact that the real line can only be partitioned into at most countable disjoint intervals?

Comment: I formalized and elaborated my understanding based upon your answer. How about reading it once? Thanks a lot.